# ScalaMock: Stub works only for first test

Tags: scala, scalamock

Recently I started usage of ScalaMock library in my unit tests and it works fine, until I want to use the same stab (declared globally in a test suite) in more than one test.

Here is an example:

```
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

trait Bank {
  def transaction(amount: Double): Double
  def deposit(amount: Double): Double
}

class OloloSuite extends FunSuite with MockFactory {
  val fakeBank = stub[Bank]
  (fakeBank.transaction _).when(10.0).returns(9.0)
  (fakeBank.deposit _).when(10.0).returns(11.0)

  //Pass
  test("Transaction test") {
    assert(fakeBank.transaction(10.0) === 9.0)
  }

  //Fails
  test("Deposit test") {
    assert(fakeBank.deposit(10.0) === 11.0)
  }
}
```

How to make "Deposit test" pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please read the docs here: http://scalamock.org/user-guide/sharing-scalatest/

Your options:

- mix in OneInstancePerTest with your test suite
- or create a fixture (see link above for example)

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix for this is to move "expectation" functions inside of the tests:

```
val fakeBank = stub[Bank]

test("Transaction test") {
  (fakeBank.transaction _).when(10.0).returns(9.0).anyNumberOfTimes()
  assert(fakeBank.transaction(10.0) === 9.0)
}

test("Deposit test") {
  (fakeBank.deposit _).when(10.0).returns(11.0).anyNumberOfTimes()
  assert(fakeBank.deposit(10.0) === 11.0)
}
```

But it's still not convenient if you want to have the same result for different tests :(